How to order a Captain Morgan and Coke
I can order a Rum and Coke with:
ラムとコーラをください
However, I do not like regular rum, only Captain Morgan spiced rum, so I want to be very specific in my request.
In the US, usually I can just say "Captain and Coke, please". However, in Japan, I am not sure how popular some of our drinks/brands are. On my last trip, I was unsuccessful trying to ask for Captain Morgan and Coke in English.
Would this be correct? Note: this is my guess trying to spell out Captain Morgan rum.
キャプテンモルガンラムとコーラをください
Update:
From two liquor stores in Japan, I found that this is the correct product name in Japanese:

キャプテンモルガン　スパイスドラム

Reference: link and link

キャプテンモルガンというラムとコーラでおねがいします

@weeab00 - How does と いう work in your example? I looked this up at https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86-to-iu-meaning/ and I am still not sure. Rum called Captain Morgan?

という can be parsed any number of ways here.  "A rum called Captain Morgan" would work.  But という is often a way to modify another word.

I think you should first ask if they have Captain Morgan.

@aguijonazo - good suggestion.

This brand is not well-known in Japan, so if you go to a random izakaya and say this, the staff will probably be confused. At a specialized liquor store or bar, after you confirm they have it (e.g., on the menu), you can simply say "キャプテンモルガンをください" (there's no need to add "ラム" in such places). Just saying "キャプテン" is unlikely to be understood.
Moreover, if you order by saying "キャプテンモルガンとコーラをください", you'll probably get two separate glasses, one with Captain Morgan and one with plain Coke. If you want them mixed, you need to say something like "キャプテンモルガンのコーラ割りをください". [base alcohol]の[mixer]割り is a useful phrase to order custom cocktails. Common mixing methods include 水割り, お湯割り, ウーロン茶割り, ソーダ割り and オレンジジュース割り. Alternatively, in simple cases like "rum and coke", you can drop と and say ラムコーク, カシスソーダ, マリブオレンジ and so on.

Thank you for the details. I did not know about 割り. I will learn the other split expressions.
